# ng-sortable com array bi direcional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sortable

preciso percorrer um `array` de `array` e criar listas separadas, usando o `ng-sortable` pro usuário pode alterar as posições dos dados.

Array()

```
$scope.teste = [{'julio' : 16, 'emerson' : 14, 'aspas' : 13},
                {'fernando' : 22, 'robson' : 25, 'semedo' : 24, 'kaio' : 27},
                {'luiz' : 37, 'armando' : 41, 'aroldo' : 51}];
```

meu html:

```
<ul class="list-group" 
    ui-sortable="sortableOptions"
    ng-repeat="(key, data) in teste track by $index"
    ng-model="key" class="list">

    <li ng-repeat="(k, d) in data track by $index"
        ng-model="k"
        class="ui-state-default">
            {{k}} : {{d}}
    </li>
</ul>

{{teste}}
```

meu `sortableOptions`

```
$scope.sortableOptions = { connectWith: '.connectedItemsExample .list' };
```

Erro:

```
Error: ngModel.$modelValue.splice is not a function wireUp/callbacks.stop
```

com uma lista só usando `array` funciona normal, mas percorrer `array` de `array` e pra cada `array` criar uma lista, esse código não serve.

Comment: qual é o valor das tuas `sortableOptions` ?

Comment: parece que o problema é em usar, array com indices